# Is there an equivalent method to Delphi's System.Frac?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi

I am looking for a method equivalent to Delphi's `System.Frac` in .NET.

The Delphi function strips the whole number leaving just the value after the decimal point.

I could write my own method but thought I would check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know of no such function, and I don't think it exists. Such a function would be part of the `Math` class, and I can't see it there. So you'll have to go with `value-Math.Truncate(value)`:

```
public static double Frac(double value)
{
  return value-Math.Truncate(value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply.  Having had a further search I have also found that modulus 1 works. I.e. value % 1; Both answers of which handle a minus value correctly too.

Comment: @Self Actually the modulus could result in accuracy issues.  (I assume due to floating point math).

Comment: `value % 1.0` works because it isn't the modulus, but the remainder. Surprisingly it's a tiny bit faster than my variant.

Comment: Good point!  Also reduces overhead slightly if used outside of an additional method. ... I should have said 'modulus operator'.

Comment: Have also found that there is an IEEERemained method provided by the .NET framework so Math.IEEERemained(value, 1.0);

Answer (score 0):

try this  [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1375680.aspx/1?how%20to%20get%20the%20fractional%20part%20of%20double)

```
 double value, fraction;
 value = 8.24;
 fraction = value - (int) value;
```

OR

```
Decimal d=1.58M;
Decimal fractional=d-Decimal.Truncate(d);
```

Comment: First one suffers from the limited range of `int`, the second one does not return the fractional part for negative numbers(-0.25 => 0.75) and might also suffer from rounding issues. The final one is correct.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my bad.i removed it